Make interval for PROGRESSFUNCTION in PHP CURL?
With below code
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progress_upload');

progress_upload function will be triggered many times in a second but how can we set an interval to decrease it?

Have you tried to slow it down by including a usleep() in the callback function? Note that CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION is deprecated.

How delay can be helpful? I want to run function for example every 5 seconds.

I haven't tested this, but I assume that the call back function won't be called again until it has finished. Adding a delay to it will therefore slow it down.

You can also use a tiny trick in your body function like below
function progress_upload()
{
    
    //contain time of next run
    static $next ;

    $INTERVAL = 5; // unit is second

    $now = time();

    if ( $now > $next ){

      //function body here
      //
      //
      //

      $next = $now + $INTERVAL;

    }

}



This is also a good idea. I would be happier with this if it said:  static $next = 0;. If you replace $next = $now + $INTERVAL; by $next += $INTERVAL; you use $now only once, so you can simply replace it by time(). Simpler is better.

With this i can send message on specific progress percent!

I believe you want to set the BUFFERSIZE (in bytes) so that it will download in larger chunks:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 2048);

Note: Someone mentioned that CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION is deprecated, I can see that how it works changes after 5.5.0 - but nowhere can I see that this feature will be removed.

For de deprication message see: CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION explained. In the PHP manual see: CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION. Using the old one is, at the moment, not a disaster.
